# How to identify the error in logcat

Tags: android, android-logcat

I have some error in logcat but i dont know how to identify it. pls help me to find out this problem. My system crashes after running the emulator. I don't know what is an error in my project.

Thanks in advance.

```
02-14 16:45:44.527: D/dalvikvm(562): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
02-14 16:45:46.407: I/ActivityThread(562): Pub polito.mailandroid: polito.mailandroid.ui.ElementProvider
02-14 16:45:46.417: D/AndroidRuntime(562): Shutting down VM
02-14 16:45:46.417: W/dalvikvm(562): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
02-14 16:45:46.487: E/AndroidRuntime(562): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 16:45:46.487: E/AndroidRuntime(562): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider polito.mailandroid.ui.ElementProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: polito.mailandroid.ui.ElementProvider
02-14 16:45:46.487: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4240)
02-14 16:45:46.487: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:3992)
02-14 16:45:46.487: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3946)
02-14 16:45:46.487: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-14 16:45:46.487: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1185)
02-14 16:45:46.487: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-14 16:45:46.487: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-14 16:45:46.487: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-14 16:45:46.487: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 16:45:46.487: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-14 16:45:46.487: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-14 16:45:46.487: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-14 16:45:46.487: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-14 16:45:46.487: E/AndroidRuntime(562): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: polito.mailandroid.ui.ElementProvider
02-14 16:45:46.487: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
02-14 16:45:46.487: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
02-14 16:45:46.487: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
02-14 16:45:46.487: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4225)
02-14 16:45:46.487: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  ... 12 more
02-14 16:46:16.637: I/Process(562): Sending signal. PID: 562 SIG: 9
02-14 17:00:46.667: I/ActivityThread(644): Pub polito.mailandroid: polito.mailandroid.ui.ElementProvider
02-14 17:00:46.667: D/AndroidRuntime(644): Shutting down VM
02-14 17:00:46.717: W/dalvikvm(644): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
02-14 17:00:46.727: E/AndroidRuntime(644): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 17:00:46.727: E/AndroidRuntime(644): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider polito.mailandroid.ui.ElementProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: polito.mailandroid.ui.ElementProvider
02-14 17:00:46.727: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4240)
02-14 17:00:46.727: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:3992)
02-14 17:00:46.727: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3946)
02-14 17:00:46.727: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-14 17:00:46.727: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1185)
02-14 17:00:46.727: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-14 17:00:46.727: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-14 17:00:46.727: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-14 17:00:46.727: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 17:00:46.727: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-14 17:00:46.727: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-14 17:00:46.727: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-14 17:00:46.727: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-14 17:00:46.727: E/AndroidRuntime(644): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: polito.mailandroid.ui.ElementProvider
02-14 17:00:46.727: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
02-14 17:00:46.727: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
02-14 17:00:46.727: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
02-14 17:00:46.727: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4225)
02-14 17:00:46.727: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  ... 12 more
02-14 17:09:00.347: I/ActivityThread(692): Pub polito.mailandroid: polito.mailandroid.ui.ElementProvider
02-14 17:09:00.437: D/AndroidRuntime(692): Shutting down VM
02-14 17:09:00.437: W/dalvikvm(692): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
02-14 17:09:00.457: E/AndroidRuntime(692): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 17:09:00.457: E/AndroidRuntime(692): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{polito.mailandroid.ui/polito.mailandroid.ui.ui.LoginUI}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: polito.mailandroid.ui.ui.LoginUI
02-14 17:09:00.457: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
02-14 17:09:00.457: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
02-14 17:09:00.457: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-14 17:09:00.457: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
02-14 17:09:00.457: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-14 17:09:00.457: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-14 17:09:00.457: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-14 17:09:00.457: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 17:09:00.457: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-14 17:09:00.457: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-14 17:09:00.457: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-14 17:09:00.457: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-14 17:09:00.457: E/AndroidRuntime(692): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: polito.mailandroid.ui.ui.LoginUI
02-14 17:09:00.457: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
02-14 17:09:00.457: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
02-14 17:09:00.457: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
02-14 17:09:00.457: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
02-14 17:09:00.457: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
02-14 17:09:00.457: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: polito.mailandroid.ui.ui.LoginUI - this is your errer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i.e error from the Logcat

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: polito.mailandroid.ui.ElementProvider
>   02-14 16:45:46.487: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)

Answer (score 1):

The classes `polito.mailandroid.ui.ui.LoginUI` and `polito.mailandroid.ui.ElementProvider` were not found. You should check the .apk and your build script to include them.

Answer (score 1):

Its class Not found exception.

make sure class you are using is exists or not and do entry in manifest of particular activity.

Answer (score 1):

The error is

```
02-14 17:00:46.727: E/AndroidRuntime(644): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: polito.mailandroid.ui.ElementProvider
```

Have you forgotten to declare your ContentProvider in AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 1):

You are facing a `RuntimeException` that was not handled. It is `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: polito.mailandroid.ui.ElementProvider` because most probably you did not define it in the Manifest file

Comment: some actvity have <android:permission="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS">  this permission,should i remove this.

Comment: adding extra permissions will not give exceptions. You should have each class (activity, service, ... etc) defined in the Manifest file. Please show the Manifest xml file to have a clear view.

Answer (score 1):

Your are facing this error please see to it

```
02-14 16:45:46.487: E/AndroidRuntime(562): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider polito.mailandroid.ui.ElementProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: polito.mailandroid.ui.ElementProvider
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems ur new to java . Read about Exception in java that will help .And for the time being look for error which contains the name of the package or file and read the Caused By error .